# Ubuntu 17.10 won't start after update

Tags: 16.04, boot, 17.10

I don't have much knowledge about Linux systems, but my computer has requested to update from 16.04 to 17.10 yesterday, and now it doesn't start. It gets stuck on the ubuntu logo.

I've already tried to fix the GRUB without success.

Can you please help?

What sort of information should I provide? (please make sure that you leave all the commands that I need to run)

Comment: I have the same issue. After choosing Ubuntu in Grub.. it keeps on checking something and then I can see the mouse pointer for few seconds.. and then it's go.. and so on.